# Path integral on Riemann surface is determined only by homology class of path

Tags: integration, homology-cohomology, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces, differential

I heard thanks to Cauchy theorem, we can say path integral on Riemann surface is determined only by homology class of the path.

That is, let $ω$ be holomorphic 1-form differential on Riemann surface $X$.∮ω on the path $r$ and $∮ω$ on the path $r'$ are the same if two paths $r$ and $r'$ are homologous.

I understand in this direction, we use cauchy theorem.
But how to prove the other direction, that is, how to prove

> if integral are the same, the paths are homologous.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The other direction is simply false. You are probably confusing this with deRham (or Hodge-deRham) theorem that integration gives an isomorphism between singular (co)homology of a surface with real coefficients and its de Rham cohomology or, for a compact surface, the space of harmonic 1-forms.

Comment: Could you give me a counter example?

Comment: This is a simple dimension count: If $S$ has genus $g\ge 1$ then $dim(H^1(S, {\mathbb C}))=2g$ while the dimension of the space of holomorphic 1-forms is $g$.

Comment: I don't really see what is happening. Let think of integrating dx/y on E(C), which path on torus which is not homologous gives the same integral value?

Comment: Wait, can't we simply consider $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0,1\}$ and conisder two small circles with centers at 0 and 1, respectively? Then, $\oint \left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)dz$ along this circles are equal to $2\pi i$, but, of course, the corresponding paths are not homotopic.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought it is "homotopy", not "homology". Nevermind.